install font from .woff file?
I am given a font file (.woff and .woff2).
However when I open the file it doesn't directly open in the installer, instead of going that it's going to textedit.
When I open the font book, and drag the file to there, the following error pops up:

None of the files selected contain fonts that can be installed on macOS. Check your selection and try again.


What do you want to do with that font?  Wolf format is intended to be put on a server so that it can be displayed in properly encoded web pages.

I wish to use them in type editors to give the same branding as our website etc. The organization has provided those files for us to use.

Have you asked if the organization could give you the normal .ttf or .otf format versions that are standard  for local use for creating documents or emails?

You have a license allowing these fonts to be used in print media?

macOS does not support web fonts (outside of rendering web pages).

macOS supports TrueType (.ttf), Variable TrueType (.ttf), TrueType
Collection (.ttc), OpenType and OpenType-SVG (.otf), and OpenType
Collection (.ttc) fonts. Legacy suitcase TrueType fonts and PostScript
Type 1 LWFN fonts might work but aren’t recommended.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/font-book/fntbk1000/mac
However, there are plenty of utilities that convert fonts from one format to another. There's always FontForge, if all else fails.
I would avoid using a website service to do the conversion, as you don't know if they keep a copy of the font...
(FWIW, Windows doesn't support web fonts on the desktop, either.)
